# mongoimport: how to include fieldnames

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

mongoimport correctly imports like this [tab separated, but file extension csv]:

```
 ./mongoimport -d gdelt -c events --file 20131115.export.csv --type tsv --headerline
```

Since the file has no headerline i have specified a [long] list of fieldnames in a file, one field per line. In the mongodb documentation i see that i specify that filename for the import:

```
./mongoimport -d gdelt -c events --file 20131115.export.csv --fieldFile fieldnames --type tsv --headerline
```

This does not make any difference. There is no error message, but the file still imports without fieldnames. I have tried the -f option, and also to remove --headerline, all with the same result. The import file placed both at the database path and the bin directory.

The question: how can i add fieldnames in mongoimport using the --fieldFile option?

```
session info:
Fri Nov 22 17:13:38.356 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=15260 port=27017       
dbpath=/storage/henk/data/GDELT/CSV 64-bit host=crunchbang
Fri Nov 22 17:13:38.356 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.8
```

Database: http://gdelt.utdallas.edu/data/dailyupdates/?O=D
field names: http://gdelt.utdallas.edu/data/lookups/CSV.header.dailyupdates.txt

Comment: Definitely remove `--headerline`.  I just tested this, and it works properly for me.  Can you post samples of the file and the fieldFile?  If you remove `--headerline`, this is the correct import command.

Comment: @idbentley - thanks-i have removed the entire database and run the same line without --headerline, it works now.

Comment: Er...almost. Mongodb does not want to add the first 2 fieldnames somehow. I have added the field names and the database in the question above.

Comment: Make sure that in your header file, each field name is on a new line.  When I look at the sample file you provided, they are all on one line.

Comment: @ idbentley - i had replaced the tabs in the header file by returns, and the last line in the text file is empty. somehow the first 2 lines are skipped, even when i replace them with dummies. there was no problem importing this file into SQLite with these headers.